# Comparing ints in Java

Tags: java, equality

I was under impression that when looking for equality between 2 `int`s == test is sufficient

As part of `equals()`, i

```
    if (this.getDayOfWeek() != that.getDayOfMonth()) {
        return false;
    }
```

Where getDayOfWeek is defined as

```
    public int getDayOfWeek() {
        return calendarInstance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }
```

Ok, so we get 2 `int`s here. Both are 1. And not the same (according to `equals`)

Please help me understand why is `1 != 1`

Answer (score 10):

```
if (this.getDayOfWeek() != that.getDayOfMonth())
```

There's your problem.  You're comparing day of the week to day of the month, which probably aren't equal most of the time.

But to answer your original question.  Yes, == is sufficient for `int` but not for `Integer` which requires the use of `equals()`

Comment: ---which probably aren't equal most of the time.  +1

Answer (score 0):

have you make sure that both of the data compared are the same by printing out their values and types? in addition, if you refer to this http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/other/10time/30calendar.html, DayOfMonth is range from (1-31) whereby DayOfWeek is range from (0-6)